# tikz positioning images relative to page and content

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics

here is a piece of code that will put an image on the left of the page and one on the right. I need to find another way of positioning the images so that by just repeating this code, lualatex appends the new content appropriately.

Instead of \path (0,0) i need something that will place the image (anchored at the top left) on the left side of the page underneath the text if there is, or at the top left corner, and the second horizontally aligned with the first (both anchor from top) but on the right side of the page against the margin. "(0,0)" are absolute coordinates, therefore if i just repeat the code for a new pair of images, i'll have to manually tune these coordinates manually for each new pair of images.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.callouts}
\graphicspath{ {/../items/} }
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 13 mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
  note/.style = {rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={(#1)},
                 callout pointer width=4mm, 
                 draw, ultra thick, rounded corners,
                 text width=41mm, inner sep=3mm, font=\large}
                    ]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)  [box,  left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: i just realized that repeating the whole "tikzpicture" environment allows appending of additional material by keeping "\path   (0,0)  node" without overlapping. Therefore is there a way to declare

```
node distance = 8mm and 13 mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
  note/.style = {rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={(#1)},
                 callout pointer width=4mm, 
                 draw, ultra thick, rounded corners,
                 text width=41mm, inner sep=3mm, font=\large}
                    ]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
```

without having to rewrite it each time.

In the comments i was asking for a solution using only tabular and tcolorbox, i.e. not using tikz at all.

My goal with tabularx is to make a 3-column one like this "lXr", in which columns 1 and 3 will hold the 2 images, and the textboxes will go in 2 in a left aligned environment. minipage allows that and also defining a specific height and fill from bottom.

EDIT2:
i would like to show the change i did to the solution given here by another user:

```
%\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio} % the image size will be appropriately set for each case.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics[height=40mm]{jpg/albIe7h}}
(\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)   [box,  left] {\includegraphics[height=30mm]{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [note={-9mm,1mm},
            right=40mm of cardbox.north west, yshift=-15mm]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [note={17mm,2mm},
            below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. Now is not possible to see what is your problem. This fragment can be placed anywhere on the page.

Comment: did it. Could you make a solution only with tabular and tcolorboxes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Please, be more clear. Show us, what you try so far (in form an MWE) and where you stuck in your effort. See answer below.

Comment: Please consider removing your rant, it doesn't add anything to your question.

Comment: i'll remove it. It's not a rant. One person asked me for clarification on the probem i'm facing with his solution.

Comment: As I see, now you copy part od my answer as your question ... what is now your question and what you like to say with this? It would be fairer to accept my answer than doing this (plagiarism)!

Comment: why plagiarism? I mentioned that i took it from the solution of another user here. If allowed i will even mention your nick. I made it clear that i have a problem of alignment with your solution when using images of different aspect ratio. If your "anger" or "blame" is about the fact that i have not yet validated your answer then, please note that i was willing to do that since the beginning but here i was stopped by this problem of alignment.

Comment: This is programming and any experienced user knows how long it takes to setup something until it is satisfying in this field. Document writing through programming is not a mere task. If only there were a mean to show you in a convincing way how much i appreciate your help. Let me tell you that i'm trying to create a working template that i will use to produce a lot of documents that many will read.

Answer (score 2):

To long for a comment ...

Sorry, but I lost in your question and comment. I can't figured out what is the problem. For example, the following (no so short)MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts
                }
\tikzset{
node distance = 8mm and 13 mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
  note/.style = {rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={(#1)},
                 callout pointer width=4mm,
                 draw, ultra thick, rounded corners,
                 text width=41mm, inner sep=3mm, font=\large}
        }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)   [box,  left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [note={-9mm,1mm},
            right=of cardbox.east]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [note={17mm,2mm},
            below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};

\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)   [box,  left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [note={-9mm,1mm},
            right=of cardbox.east]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [note={17mm,2mm},
            below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)   [box,  left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [note={-9mm,1mm},
            right=of cardbox.east]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [note={17mm,2mm},
            below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see from MWE, definitions for image elements styles are moved in preamble in `\tikzset`. By this it not need anymore to be repeated at each picture.

From picture you can see, that images are nicely fit between left and right text borders and that the first on the page is at top of text area.

My conclusions:

- the code of image works as expected, you only need to insert in your document properly (I use `center` environment, but you can use for example `figure` float or some else.
- I'm not able to figured out, what actually is your problem (as I already mentioned on beginning of answer).
- It is not clear, where you have tables and `tcolorbox`es and what they are related to tis images or your problem. Please, clarify this by editing your question

**Addendum:**
Small improvements of above answer. Now the notifications have the same distance from the left edge, defined are separate style for the left and the right directed notes and for left and right boxes with image. Let me emphasize, that all is based on guessing what to OP is after:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts
                }
\tikzset{
node distance = 2mm and 55mm,
    boxL/.style = {inner sep=0pt, below #1, anchor=north west},
    boxR/.style = {inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east},
noteBase/.style = {rectangle callout, callout pointer width=4mm,
                   draw=blue, ultra thick, line join=round,
                   text width=32mm, minimum height=2.2\baselineskip, inner sep=2mm},
   noteL/.style = {noteBase, callout relative pointer={(-11mm,1mm)}},
   noteR/.style = {noteBase, callout relative pointer={(+17mm,2mm)}},
        }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (n1)  [boxL=right] {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (n2)  [boxR=left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [noteL, right=of n1.west]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [noteR, below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};

\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[66]

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (n1)  [boxL=right] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (n2)  [boxR=left] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}};
\node (n3) [noteL, right=of n1.west]
           {Ceci est une boîte\\ This is a box};
\node (n4) [noteR, below=of n3]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path   (0,0)           node (n1)  [boxL=right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (n2)  [boxR=left] {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n3) [noteL, right=of n1.west]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n4) [noteR, below=of n3]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There were mistakes. I rewrote my post. But yet i have to test your solution.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking for another solution is that tikz' language is not precise and scientific. For example, in my previous concern, for adding a new pair of images i could have done "\node (newcardbox) [box, left, below=20mm of cardbox] ..."
but for the second image of the pair, which was introduced with "(\linewidth,0)  node (bottle)  [box,  left]..." I really don't see how to set the coordinates so that it puts the image against the right margin (the image's right side being the anchor) and its top horizontally aligned with "newcardbox"'s top.

Comment: In the same language spirit as of "below=20mm of cardbox" i would imagine something like "right=of newcardbox against right margin" or "right=\linewidth of newcarbox" but tikz does not understand or in the latter does not do what i want because it takes wrong anchors and it doesn't offer a way to precise them. Tikz while it offers more than one way of doing one thing, so far i have not seen any consistent language. The documentation is written like a novel, and is HUGE. Just have a look at python and perl to see what i mean by "scientifically".

Comment: @user1850133, sorry then your question is unclear. That TikZ is not "scientific` but `tcolorbox` is (regardless that it is based on `tikz`) ?

Comment: i did not say tcolorbox is. I suggested to use tabular as i explained. This way no node is needed. The simplest way i know to make a textbox is tcolorbox. tabular and minipage should help in positioning the box. But i tried and so far, it still didn't work.

Comment: could you try your solution with images of different aspect ratio with \setkeys{Gin}{width=2cm,keepaspectratio}. I'm seeing quite a lot of misalignment.