# images textboxes aligned and anchored to cells of non-visible table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, luatex, tcolorbox

I need to put pairs of images, one image against the left margin of the page, the other against the right with their top side horizontally aligned. I'd like to achieve it with a non-visible table. The images top must coincide with the top of the row in which they are. I need to put textboxes (callout or with another kind of pointer), 2 per pair of images and just next to the left one. These should be one on the other with always the same spacing in-between (2 or 3 mm is be fine). The bottom textbox's lower-left corner must be at the bottom-left corner of the cell of the table in which it is. I did it with lowriter with slightly visible table for info.
Using a table for anchoring is to ensure alignment despite different image sizes, textbox sizes.
here it is
[image]

Comment: what you try so far? After so many answers on similar questions we expect some MWE, Writing code from scratch is not fun ...

Comment: I highlighted in the comments in my previous post, a problem of alignment of the textboxes occuring because of images with different aspectratio. I'm trying to overcome this by changing the anchor point but still it is not satisfactory because of different vertical spacings due to different images height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that something similar to this is what is wanted:

[image]

in this case a `tcbposter` can be used as the base layer to place all items over this page. The `poster` defines a regular matrix with desired rows and columns. Insade this sctructure it's possible to use `tcolorboxes` or `TikZ nodes`.  The structure define inner nodes which can be used as reference for placing other elements. But also every new box can be labelled (`name=...`) and serve also as reference.

Previous diagram has been drawn with `showframe` option in `poster` parameters. This shows the grid, columns, rows and boxes labels. You have to suppres it to avoid printing this information.

The code (with some lines from [Zarko`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630465/1952) to [tikz positioning images relative to page and content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630453/1952) is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts, positioning}

\tikzset{
  note/.style = {rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={(#1)},
                 callout pointer width=4mm,
                 draw, ultra thick, rounded corners,
                 text width=41mm, inner sep=3mm, font=\large}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {showframe,spacing=0pt, columns=4, rows=5},
boxes
= {empty},
]
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=left]{name=B11,column=1,row=1}{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3cm]{caixa}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=left]{name=B12,column=1,row=2}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3.8cm]{caixa}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=left]{name=B13,column=1,row=3}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.8cm]{caixa}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=left]{name=B14,column=1,row=4}{\includegraphics[width=3.4cm, height=4cm]{caixa}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=left]{name=B15,column=1,row=5}{\includegraphics[width=2.2cm, height=3.5cm]{caixa}}


\node [note={17mm,2mm}, anchor=south] (n1) at (TCBPOSTER@col2.center|-TCBPOSTER@row1.south) 
{That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};

\node [note={-9mm,1mm}, above=2mm of n1] (n2) {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};


\posterbox[valign=top, halign=right]{name=B41,column=4,row=1}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=3.2cm]{botella}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=right]{name=B42,column=4,row=2}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3.8cm]{botella}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=right]{name=B43,column=4,row=3}{\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=3.4cm]{botella}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=right]{name=B44,column=4,row=4}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.3cm]{botella}}
\posterbox[valign=top, halign=right]{name=B45,column=4,row=5}{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.8cm]{botella}}


\end{tcbposter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want as for the frame concept as it supports textboxes containing newlines. Meanwhile, could you manage to get the images really anchored at the cell corners as it is in the image that i posted?

Comment: @user1850133 Just change `boxes=empty` by `boxes=blankest` in `tcbposter` parameters.

Comment: perfect. Since the title is not set here, i did "\node [anchor=north] (title) at (TCBPOSTER@col2.east|-TCBPOSTER@row1.north)
{\huge title};" and change valign=top to valign=bottom It does what i want.

Answer (score 1):

I already solved your problem in my answer on your previous question (without use of table). However, if you persist to have solution with table (and not be willing to show us what you try so far), below is MWE which can serve as starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts
                }
\tikzset{
  node distance = 2mm,
noteBase/.style = {rectangle callout, callout pointer width=4mm,
                   draw=blue, ultra thick, line join=round,
                   text width=32mm, minimum height=2.2\baselineskip, inner sep=2mm},
   noteL/.style = {noteBase, callout relative pointer={(-11mm,1mm)}},
   noteR/.style = {noteBase, callout relative pointer={(+17mm,2mm)}},
        }
\newcommand\Notes[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \node (n1) [noteL]  {#1};
        \node (n2) [noteR, below=of n1] {#2};
        \end{tikzpicture}
                    }
        

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[l] Q[c,f] X[r]},
           row{even} = {ht=33mm},
            row{odd} = {ht=11mm},
              colsep = 0pt,
              rowsep = 0pt,
              hlines={dashed}, vlines={dashed} % <--  delete in the real document
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{h}
\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{h}
            \includegraphics[width=2.5cm, height=3.2cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck} \\
    &   \Notes{one}
              {two}
        &       \\
%
\SetCell[r=2]{h}
\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3.8cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{h}
            \includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=3.2cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}   \\
    &   \Notes{this could be a longer piece of text including new lines}
              {here two}
        &       \\
%
\SetCell[r=2]{h}
\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2.8cm, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{h}
            \includegraphics[width=1.4cm,height=2.4cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}   \\
    &   \Notes{this could be a longer piece of text}
              {here two}
        &       \\  
%
\SetCell[r=2]{h}
\includegraphics[width=2.2cm, height=4cm, valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{h}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2.8cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}   \\
    &   \Notes{rext and newlines}
              {here too}
        &
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

In table are preserve dashed lines that table cells are better visible. In real document yo should remove them.

[image]

**Edit:**
Regarding to your comment:

- In above MWE replace `colspec = {X[l] Q[c,f] X[r]},` with for example with `colspec = {X[0.8, l] Q[l,f] X[1.2,r]},`
- After this I compile changed MWE with LuaLaTeX, I get the following result:

[image]

- Compilation went smooth, no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes.
- Is this what you after?

Comment: I said that the text boxes must be just next the the left images. Also in the textboxes in the lowriter template "newline" means "\\" or \newline. I tried, lualatex and it seem tabularray is not in my installation, though i use texlive.

Comment: Sorry @user1850133, you are unclear again. Boxes are next to the left boxes. You not provide the maximum width of images on the left nor on the right side (frankly said, you not provide any information about your document), so you left us to guess what you after. Try to replace `colspec = {X[0.8, l] Q[l,f] X[1.2,r]},` with `colspec = {X[l] Q[c,f] X[1.2,r]},` and see if then result  is netter.  What you mean with "Also in the textboxes in the lowriter template "newline" means "\\" or \newline", I cant figured out, sorry. My test with LuaLaTeX went without problems. Install `tabularrasy`!

Comment: The template done with lowriter is quite expressive. In "this could be a longer piece of text including new lines" in your solution where is the newline? Did you try newline in your textboxes?